# Overloading and inheritance

Tags: java, oop

Suppose that I have these classes:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
```

Also

```
static void call(A a) { System.out.print("A"); }
static void call(B b) { System.out.print("B"); }
public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    A b = new B();
    call(a);
    call(b);
}
```

What I am getting as output is: AA

while I was expecting: AB

I am wondering why?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I am wondering why?

- **Because the reference type is `A`.**
- Overloaded methods are bound at compile time. So at compile time
  only, the compiler knows that method of class A is to be called as
  the type of reference variable `b` is `A`.
- Always remember, **Which overloaded method to be called is decided at
  compile time based on the reference type of variable**

Slightly more explained,

```
A b = new B();
```

This line means that reference variable `b` refers to the object of class `B` but it is of type `A` and as per the rule above, the compiler knows at compile time only that the `call` method to be called should of class `A`

**EDIT :** as suggested by Subhrajyoti. 
As Subhrajyoti has rightly said, **This is compile time polymorphism**.

Comment: Well explained answer.

Comment: It is compile time polymorphism

Comment: @JunedAhsan Your comment is a possible duplicate of mine.. :D

Comment: @MarounMaroun I read somewhere "great minds think alike" :-p ;-)

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder Your comment is the exact term,Prasad should add in his answer :)

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder thanks for the exact term, edited the answer :)

Comment: @sureshatta, your wish is my command :)

Answer (score 1):

The type of the variable `b` is `A`. Static methods are called on the declared class of a variable, not on the actual runtime contents of it, so `call(b)` is bound as `call(A b)`.

Answer (score 0):

### Overloaded call binding is done at compile type using static type

Java uses ***static type*** or ***reference type*** for deciding the call for overloading at compile time and ***not the runtime*** type.

So as static type of `b` is `A`, the method that takes argument `A` is called.

`call(b) //Now compiler sees that reference type is A`

so binds this call with `call(A a)` and **not** `call(B b)`

Answer (score 0):

For static methods you do not have polymorphism. Static method is bound to class. If you have reference to `A` then you cal static method from `A`

Answer (score 0):

What you expecting is method overriding.In that case these two call method should be part of different class ,one in parent and one in child and in that case both method signature should be exactly same/matching.

Also as your method is static ,so you should remember that static method is not overridden.However you can write static method with same signature and name in child class but that will be called method hiding.

And when you call overridden method the binding of method call to its definition happens at runtime based on type of object referred by reference variable.

Answer (score 0):

By convention it's not recomended to use static fields in such maner for more readability. As you see you have some confusion.

Use all static fields like this 'A.call(some variable)' not  'new A().call(some variable)'.